# Need a simple spring web app to put and get messages from IBM Websphere MQv7

Tags: java, spring-mvc, ibm-mq

I want to develop a simple web application using spring 3.0 for reading and putting messages from and to IBM Websphere MQ. I am using MQv7. I know how to create a a Queue Manager and local queues in it and start the listener using MQ Command.

So, now I want to put a message using java code and also read a message using java code in Spring 3. I want it spring MVC model.

Answer (score 0):

Websphere MQ, provides you with a java API.
[**`Here`**](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/docs/V7.0/csqzaw17.pdf) is your reference, on how to use java API for Websphere MQ.

You can get the necessary jar files from your MQ installation directory(in windows they will be here: C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\java\lib)

Import them in your java project. It hardly matters to the API, which framework you use.You should know the basics of the framework and you can easily build your MQ app.